# How to access cert files in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, certificate

I have a React native app that utilizes the Apple Music API to display user playlists.

I have a key file that I need to use to get my developer token as apart of this, and I'm trying to find a way to read the file. Since it's on my local I cannot use fetch to get the key file as it will call it from the localhost where my web app is housed. T

he fs/promises readFile method cannot be used in React as its incompatible with the current version of React.

This is my current code:

```
private async readPrivateKey(): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(private_key_path);
    
    if (response.ok) {
      const privateKeyContent = await response.text();
      return privateKeyContent;
    } else {
      console.error(`Failed to read private key: ${response.statusText}`);
      throw new Error('Failed to read private key');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to read private key: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

It fetches the key using this path: "http://localhost:5173/key/key.p8" which is causing my issues.

Any thoughts/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch` method cannot read local files, for this case you need to use the RNFS module.
Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs

pseudocode example

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const readPrivateKey = async () => {
  const filePath = '/key/key.p8';
  const privateKeyContent = await RNFS.readFile(filePath);

  return privateKeyContent;
};
```